# jmeter testing - sending 300 threads but transaction only 40/s max?

Tags: apache, jmeter

I've been doing some load testing with JMETER. Somethings confuses me.

I've been trying to send 300 threads to the http request apache webserver. However the transaction / seconds never reach above 40. Is there some apache configuration like max connection or max thread needed to open up so that can do a solid 300 thread testing?

The CPU utilization also never hit above 5% (server is 8 core).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there are some.

You should set properly the following:

> - for Apache:   **MaxClients + ServerLimit**
> - for Tomcat:   **maxThreads + acceptCount** (AJP/HTTP connector)

Tomcat has two settings in the Connector config file (.../tomcat/conf/server.xml):

- [maxThreads](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) - maximum number of request processing threads to be
  created by the HTTP Connector, which therefore determines the max
  number of simultaneous requests that can be handled;
- [acceptCount](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) - maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all
  possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received
  when the queue is full will be refused.

Apache settings:

- [MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) - maximum number of connections that will be processed simultaneously;
- [ServerLimit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit) - upper limit on configurable number of processes.

The last two you could set either in httpd-mpm.conf and/or httpd-mpm.conf_2.0 in your ../conf/extra/ folder, or add to httpd.conf something like the following:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    . . .
    ServerLimit 350
    MaxClients 350 
</IfModule>
```

Please note that ServerLimit value defines the upper limit of MaxClients values, so ServerLimit should be equal or greater than MaxClients.

Comment: Great! Thanks! After finding our my server running prefork MPM, i'm going to add ServerLimit 512 and Max Client 512, KeepAlive On KeepAliveTimeOut 2  so that i can further my testing with 500 threads and determine the server performance. I'm wondering are there any more settings needed to set.